# Modifying Emacs isearch key bindings to yank

Tags: emacs, hotkeys

I want to be able to use `M-v` hotkey in the emacs search mode to paste text. I know I can add the binding to the `isearch-mode-map` but when I try to bind `yank` as a method, it yanks the text in the current buffer, not the search input. How can I find which command is invoked when `C-y` is pressed in the search mode?

Comment: Use `isearch-yank-kill` instead of `yank`.

Comment: Try `(lookup-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-y"))`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Feel free to answer this. I am also interested on how to be able to find mode maps or key mappings when the minibuffer is used. Are there any tricks to do so? `lookup-key` looks helpful, but how do I find currently used mode maps when I am interacting with something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `isearch-yank-kill` instead of `yank`. Try `(lookup-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-y"))`. I use `minibuffer-inactive-mode-map`, `minibuffer-local-map`, `minibuffer-local-completion-map`. You can get exhaustive list of maps by <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>. Function `(current-local-map)` can help. See also http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Controlling-Active-Maps.html

Upd.: Name of current local keymap, definition of function `keymap-symbol`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14490054/1937596

If you use

```
(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
```

you can, while in minibuffer, call `(eval-expression)` by hotkey and execute `(current-local-map)` or `(keymap-symbol (current-local-map))`

Comment: But what would be the way to execute `(current-local-map)` while I am already in the minibuffer for example (or anything that expects some input)?

Answer (score 3):

Typing <kbd>C-s</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>C-y</kbd> will tell you:

> C-y runs the command isearch-yank-kill.

More generally, type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> whilst isearching, followed by the key sequence you want to know about. Analogous to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> when you're *not* searching, of course.

Typing <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> whilst isearching displays *all* of the isearch bindings, which is likewise analogous to the output for <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> when you're not searching.

The other isearch help bindings are <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> to show you the mode help, and <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd> which gives you a menu to all of the above.